# Halmos' Naive Set Theory, Section 5

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, set-theory

In Section 5 of Halmos' "Naive Set Theory" there is an exercise in which a collection $\mathcal{C}$ is given and it is required to interpret the following notation:
$$ \bigcup_{X \in \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{P}(X)$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the power set of X.

Now, I intuitively understand that this is the union over the collection of the power sets of all the members of $\mathcal{C}$, however to make it rigorous one has to apply the Axiom of Union which however presupposes a suitable collection to be defined. Therefore, everything boils down to constructing the collection of the power sets of the members of $\mathcal{C}$, which however I didn't manage to do. In fact, all the axioms I have at disposal (Extension, Specification, Pairing, Union, Powers) aren't fit for the job. The Axiom of Specification, especially, fails because we are not given an embedding set which contains all the subsets of the members of $\mathcal{C}$.

Does anyone have any idea of how to proceed?

As always, any answer or comment is highly appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: "It is required to interpret..." - what does it mean "interpret"? This set can be interpreted as "set of all subsets of the sets in $\mathcal C$", for example.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I should have clarified that in the context of the section it means to find a set which is reasonable to denote that way (e.g. in the same section Halmos defines a notation for the set of the complements of all the sets of a given collection, however, first it defines such set rigorously by using the Axiom of Specification). Therefore my problem is that I can not simply state by words what set it is but I need to construct it rigorously by use of the axioms I quoted and then say “we shall denote this set by…”. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: Not very clear... but we start with the assupmtion that $\mathcal C$ is a *collection* of sets. If so, we have that: for every $X \in \mathcal C, X$ is a set and thus, by Axiom of powerset, $\mathcal P(X)$ is a set. Now we consider the new collection of sets $P_C$ made of all power-sets $\mathcal P(X)$ for $X \in \mathcal C$ and apply Axiom of union that states that for every collection of sets we have the union of that collection, i.e. $\bigcup P_C = \{ \mathcal P(X) \mid X \in \mathcal C \}$,

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your answer, however my problem is exactly in forming the collection of power-sets: which principle of set construction (i.e. axiom) are we using to do it? (We can not just say “the set of all power-sets of sets in the collection $\mathcal{C}$” for that would not be a rigorous application of the Axiom of Specification without an embedding collection that contains every set.

Comment: A *collection* (see page 1) is identified by a property; thus, the collection $P_C$ is defined by the property: the set $\mathcal P(X)$ belongs to it for every $X \in \mathcal C$. The basic issue (Russell's Paradox, etc) is that not every colelction is a set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Actually, I checked and at page 1 of Halmos’ book is stated that “…to avoid terminological monotony, we shall sometimes say collection instead of set.” whereas what are you referring to is called a “class” at page 11. However, the Axiom of Union is stated for collections and not classes. Therefore, either it is just a typo or an implicit assumption that we can construct the collection of all power-sets or there is something else…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easy if you had the axiom (schema) of replacement available, but you don't, so here's an alternative approach. First form $B=\bigcup\mathcal C$, by the axiom of union. For each $X\in\mathcal C$, we have $X\subseteq B$ and therefore $\mathcal P(X)\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$, which means $\mathcal P(X)\in\mathcal{PP}(B)$. So you can obtain $\{\mathcal P(X):X\in\mathcal C\}$ by specification, using $\mathcal{PP}(B)$ as the superset required by specification. Finally, apply the axiom of union in the way you planned to get the required set.